# Oracle sql query to get parent node based on type?

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, connect-by

I need help in building a hierarchical query to get parent node based on type. For example:

```
Table (org)

pid|cid|type|name
   |  1|MGT |Ofc Pres
  1|  2|DEP |HR
  1|  3|DEP |IT
  3|  4|DIV |Web
  3|  5|DIV |Database
  4|  6|SEC |HTML
  4|  7|SEC |JAVA
```

My goal is to get the DEP given the cid (6 or 7). Using the query below, I only get the pid (4).

```
  select pid
    from org
   start
    with cid = 7
 connect
      by
   prior cid = pid
```

Appreciate any feedback.

UPDATE 07/24/2018:

Some additional info that might help.

MGT (Management) is the highest/root level
DEP (Department) is under MGT.
DIV (Division) is under DEP.
SEC (Section) is under DIV.

So if given a child id of type SEC, I need to get the DEP (Department) which it is under (which means I need to get the DIV first then the DEP). If given a child id of type DIV, then I need to get DEP which it is under.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "get the DEP"? Do you mean, stop when `type = 'DEP'`? Do you then need to get the `name` of the `DEP`? What if, going up the tree, you never hit `DEP`? (Or are you guaranteeing that you always will? Well, obviously that is not possible; if you "start with 1", you will never hit `DEP`.)

Comment: @mathguy Yes. I need to get the name/id of the parent having type of "DEP". And yes it's guaranteed that DEP will always be there. Not necessarily the next level up but it will be up there. Start will always be a level below DEP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue has already been pointed out: `connect by prior pid = cid`. To stop when the type is `DEP`, you need to add one more condition to `connect by`:

```
connect by prior pid = cid and prior type != 'DEP'
```

and add a `WHERE clause:

```
where type = 'DEP'
```

(note that the `WHERE` clause comes before `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY`).

It is not clear what you want to `SELECT`, but that should be easy.

Actually, with the simple structure you have, the `WHERE` clause would suffice. Not having the additional condition in `CONNECT BY` means that the query will do just a little more work than necessary; it will find the MGT row as well, but it will still select the unique row where `type = 'DEP'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your tree from leaf to root.

So change pid and cid:

```
 select pid
    from org
   start
    with cid = 7
 connect by prior pid = cid
```

Comment: Thanks. To get the DEP, I added in the where clause "type='DEP'". It seems to work but I wanted to check with you if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm), `PRIOR` operator refer to the parent row.

So your query should be

```
  select pid
    from org
   where level = 2 --to get DEP
 connect by prior pid = cid;
```